# How to dereference a void variable without cast

Tags: c

```
typedef void *STACK_ENTRY;

STACK_ENTRY *create_stack_entry(void *value) {
    STACK_ENTRY *entry = malloc(sizeof(*value));
    *entry = *value;
    return entry;
}
```

I tried to make a universal function to create a `STACK_ENTRY` that should be able to have any type. So I use a void pointer as a parameter. I allocate memory with the size of the type of the value and then I would like to give the value to the pointee of the `STACK_ENTRY`.

But I get the following error:

```
prog.c:34:9: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  *entry = *value;
         ^
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: how would the compiler know what the size of your dereferenced void pointer is?

Comment: @bruceg So there is no way to have such a method? I always need to know what type the value has?

Comment: "How can I fix that?", cast the pointer to `STACK_ENTRY *` and _then_ dereference that non-void pointer.

Comment: @chux Thanks. It worked.

Comment: "I always need to know what type the value has" --> No. need to know the address of the value and the size of the type.  Perhaps posting sample usages of `create_stack_entry()` would clarify your needs.

Comment: If I get it correctly you want `*entry = value;` ?

Comment: And you shouldn't do `sizeof(*value)`, probably `sizeof(*entry)`. Because sizeof void type is undefined, and is 1 with GCC extension.

Comment: It is unclear how `typedef struct { STACK_ENTRY *top; } STACK;` is part of the post.  What function, if any, does it have?

Comment: @user3528438 Are you sure about that? I want to have a pointee with the size of the value. So if I call the method with an int value for the parameter, I want it to have 4 bytes.

Comment: "I want to have a pointee with the size of the value." is not possible - in general.  Perhaps you want "... pointer to memory that has the size of the value."  IOWs, the pointer is not the size of the original value, but the memory the pointer points to has the same size.

Comment: I am struggling finding out what parameter for sizeof() I should use. @user3528438 solution doesnt work with double for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code needs to cope with size.  Pass in size when calling `create_stack_entry()`.  No cast needed.

```
 // STACK_ENTRY *create_stack_entry(void *value)
 STACK_ENTRY *create_stack_entry(void *value, size_t size) {
   STACK_ENTRY *entry = malloc(size);
   if (entry) memcpy(entry, value, size);
   return entry;
 }
```

Comment: I guess OP really wants. `STACK_ENTRY create_stack_entry(void *value, size_t size);`. The stack itself is a dynamic array. Each element is a `void *` that points to the actual data, so the `create` function should create such a `void *`.

Comment: @user3528438 Possibly.  I suspect OP's goal is evolving.  Need to see OP's sample usage of `create_stack_entry()` and its final free'ing strategy.